# Google Calendar Sync

Tags: microsoft-outlook, sync, google-calendar

Is there something other than google calendar sync that can synch my outlook calendar with my google calendar?

My corporate policy won't let me install google calendar sync on my company laptop.
I am using a web-based interface for outlook.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they won't even allow you to install google calendar sync onto the laptop, chances are other software will not be allowed.

In that case, be creative :)

e.g. --> Do they allow syncing of calendar with your phone? in this case you can sync your phone to your company and sync your phone at home, while installing google calendar sync onto your home computer...

Comment: This is a terminal where I do not have admin access. They control almost all of the apps on this machine.